# some microsoft products and XML on an interview

Tags: sql, xml, reporting-services

here's the job description:

```
Experience with data mapping/extracts tools such as Monarch and VorteXML.
Familiarity with XML documents and schemas.
Minimum 1-3 years of data analysis in SQL Server environment.
Working knowledge of TSQL and SQL Server 2000 tools such as Enterprise Manager, SQL Query Analyzer, Profiler, DTS and BCP.
Working knowledge of SQL Server Reporting Services design and administration.
BSCS or other technical degree.
Healthcare background strongly preferred.
Strong organizational and communication skills.
Strong analytical thinking, troubleshooting and ability to manage multiple, concurrent projects.
 Ability to meet deadlines while working in a fast-paced environment.
```

1. what is an XML schema? ive extracted data programmatically from XML files, but i dont understand what they mean by schema?
2. data analysis in SQL server environment - does this just mean knowing how to do joins and select statements?
3. SSRS (design and administration) - can someone please get me started on some basic tutorials where i can learn this?
4. what is Monarch and VorteXML and where can i learn the applications?

Comment: Is this the right place for this?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Most of those questions could be easily answered by a bit of internet research. This would actually give you a good prep time for an interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just planning to answer the questions and then spend about two weeks stressing your nut off once you get the job. W3Schools will give you a start with schema (.xsd files). Sql server documentation will help you with the rest (patterns and practices on microsoft site is a good read).

You've got to understand that the interviewer probably has some ideas about the answers they want to hear too.

Good luck :)

Comment: excllnt ansr . . . . . .

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know those technologies and what they're talking about, you probably shouldn't be applying.  The same goes for any job, whether or not it's in the IT field.

Comment: i'm saying you shouldn't be asking this question in the first place, and giving you advice in the process.  the answer is clearly on topic.

Comment: you have remarkable wisdom but please if you know the answer to my question please feel free to contribute

Comment: why shouldn't someone ask a question about something they don't know? How are they supposed to learn if they never ask questions? hmm remarkable wisdom indeed.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat i never said you shouldn't ask questions.  because he mentions the job description, his question implies that he was looking to apply for a job but didn't know the answers, so he wanted the answers in order to apply for a job he wouldn't necessarily be qualified for.  the accepted answer also made this assumption, so it is not unreasonable.  i'm saying you shouldn't be doing that.  the better way to ask would have been just googling the questions, or asking them separately.